# Arduino Yun AWS Shadow update timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, iot

I am currently using the AWS IoT SDK for the Arduino Yun, and I am running the example sketches (specifically the Thermostat simulator).

I modified the loop slightly (just changed the delay at the end) such that it looks like this:

```
void loop() {
  if(success_connect) {
    // If the desired temperature is set to a higher value, start heating.
    if(desiredTemp - reportedTemp > 0.001) {reportedTemp += 0.1;}
    // If the desired temperature is set to a lower value, start cooling.
    else if(reportedTemp - desiredTemp > 0.001) {reportedTemp -= 0.1;}
    dtostrf(reportedTemp, 4, 1, float_buf);
    float_buf[4] = '\0';
    sprintf_P(JSON_buf, PSTR("{\"state\":{\"reported\":{\"Temp\":%s}}}"), float_buf);
    print_log("shadow update", myClient.shadow_update(AWS_IOT_MY_THING_NAME, JSON_buf, strlen(JSON_buf), NULL, 5));
    if(myClient.yield()) {
      Serial.println("Yield failed.");
    }
    delay(10000); // CHANGED TO 10 SECONDS INSTEAD OF 1
  }
}
```

For some reason, when the loop is delayed for less than 10 seconds, the shadow update has no problem repeating. But as soon as the delay is 10 seconds or more, I get this error:

> Exception in thread Thread-4 (most likely raised during interpr 
>   [ERR] command: shadow update code: -1

I changed the CMD_TIME_OUT to a higher value in the aws_iot_config_SDK.h file, but it still seems to have no effect. The reason why I'd like the timeout delay to be larger than 10 seconds is because I want to ideally have a trigger mechanism in the arduino that would update the shadow.